# using has to or have to

Tags: american-english, british-english, pronouns, parts-of-speech, third-person

I have example of two sentences here

```
He has to write a report.'
```

with he, she,it we will be using has.

but why we are using have here instead of has with "She"

```
She doesn't have to wear a uniform to school'
```

- people need to realize that their life doesn't revolve around them only,
  is this fine or I should use dont here,

can somebody help me
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in your first example it's the verb "to have" that you're conjugating. In the second sentence your main verb, the one conjugated is "to do".

You could rewrite the second sentence to read "She hasn't got to wear a uniform to school" if you wanted :)

Comment: can you answer the part 2 as well?

Comment: The correct way to say it is "doesn't revolve...". However you could say "life don't revolve around them" to give it some... country/homie/nonchalant flavor, keeping in mind that it's gramatically incorrect really ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is the difference between the affirmative, the negative and the interrogative forms.

This is the simple present tense and *do/does/don't/doesn't* are the forms of the auxiliary.

**When the auxiliary is present, the main verb reverts to its root form, i.e. without 's'.**

We don't use an auxiliary in the affirmative: **he works hard** (except in the emphatic affirmative: **he *does* work hard!**)

In the negative and interrogative, we use the auxiliary for the third person singular (he, she, it) and the main verb reverts to the root form. Let's try the verb *to want* instead.

Affirmative: **He wants to write a report.** No *does*, so *wants* has an 's'.

Negative: **He doesn't want to write a report.** *Doesn't* is present so *want* goes to the root form.

Interrogative: **Does he want to write a report?** *Does* makes *want* revert.

So your sentence "she doesn't have to wear a uniform" is correct.

As for your other sentence: "people need to realise that their life doesn't revolve around them only", this presents other problems¹ but as far as "doesn't revolve" is concerned, that is correct.

¹Maybe you should ask another question.